# if string item is not in string array

Tags: c#

I have a string array.
I need to display buttons based on if the selected item is in the array.
I need to know how to tell the program if "(array.**NOT** Contains("string"))".
Please can anybody help me??
Thanks in advance

My code:

```
    List<string> activationids = new List<string>();
    foreach (ModuleActivation moduleactivation in activationid)
         activationids.Add(moduleactivation.ActivationID);

    string gvselectActID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

    if (activationids.Contains(gvselectActID))
    {
      activateInsert.Visible = true;
      activateUpdate.Visible = false;
      deactivate.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (activationids."NOT" Contains(gvselectActID))
    {
      activateInsert.Visible = false;
      activateUpdate.Visible = true;
      deactivate.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
     activateInsert.Visible = false;
     activateUpdate.Visible = false;
     deactivate.Visible = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to understand boolean logic better - the `if/else if/else` construct you have does not make sense with the test condition you have.

Answer (score 10):

Change:

```
else if (activationids."NOT" Contains(gvselectActID))
```

to

```
else if (!activationids.Contains(gvselectActID))
```

Answer (score 6):

Or even simpler

```
bool containsItem=activationids.Contains(gvselectActID);

activateInsert.Visible = containsItem;
activateUpdate.Visible = !containsItem;
deactivate.Visible = containsItem;
```

Comment: +1: Whilst it doesn't specifically answer the question, it is the best approach to the sample code as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

The `!` means "NOT". So you have to place it in front of the expression you need to negate;

`!activationids.Contains("blahblah");`

However, it's quite clear that if `activationids.Contains("blahblah")` is `false`, you are gonna go into the second case. Also, currently, your third block (`... else { ...`) will never be hit.

Answer (score 2):

There are two very straightforward ways to do this:

1. Not the result of the `bool` function call:

   `if(!activationids.Contains(gvselectActID))`
2. Check the result and compare it to `false`

   `if(activationids.Contains(gvselectActID) == false)`

---

However, you are checking if it contains it in the first `if()` clause, which means that the first `else` clause will be fired if it isn't contained.  There is no need to check, and there is no way that the third `else` will ever be fired.

Answer (score 2):

Contains returns true or false, sou you cannot have three branches, you can do just

```
if (activationids.Contains(gvselectActID)) // it does contain
  ...
else // it does not contain
  ...
```

there are no other possibilities

[joke]
well it could work in this case
http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx
[/joke]

Comment: if(x){doSomething();} else if(!x){doSomethingElse();} else {throw new LogicalBoundsOfUniverseExceededException();} (though strictly , if x is changed from the outside by another thread, the third condition could be hit).

Answer (score 1):

This will be enough:

```
if (activationids.Contains(gvselectActID))
{
  // Goes here if condition is true
  activateInsert.Visible = true;
  activateUpdate.Visible = false;
  deactivate.Visible = true;
}
else
{
  // Goes here if condition is false
  activateInsert.Visible = false;
  activateUpdate.Visible = true;
  deactivate.Visible = false;
}
```

There are no other possible options - there can't be a third branch.

This makes no sense:

```
if(booleanCondition)
{}
else if (!booleanCondition)
{}
else
{}
```

As by definition, if the booleanCondition is false, the else branch will be taken - there is no need to test for it being false.